# Trigger CodeDeploy when Specific Branch Pattern is created

Tags: git, webhooks, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy, aws-codecommit

I want to create a trigger like this, when a specific branch pattern  is created in codecommit it must invoke codebuild project , eg : prod/myapp-{version} (We will create release branch like this always, like prod/myapp-V1.2 ,

This was easy in jenkins as it has branch filter regex like '*/prod/*' and it will checkout latest branch starting with prod/myapp-{version} and start build) ,

The same way I need to implement in codecommit + codebuild.  How can I do that ?  Am not seeing the option for branch pattern in codebuild , only static branch name filter (like master, or tagname) in the trigger option of code commit

[image]

So it will checkout only the static branch(eg: master).

What I want is how I can pass branch pattern or regex to codebuild as ${Version} is always dynamic . I am new to AWS devops. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sreeja,  I face the same issue. Did you found or got a solution. Could you please share if so.